# segmentation fault in python3

Tags: python-3.x, segmentation-fault

I am running python3 on a Ubuntu machine and have noticed that the following block of code is fickle. Sometimes it runs just fine, other times it produces a segmentation fault. I don't understand why. Can someone explain what might be going on?

Basically what the code does is try to read S&P companies from Wikipedia and write the list of tickers to a file in the same directory as the script. If no connection to Wikipedia can be established, the script tries instead to read an existing list from file.

```
from urllib import request
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import pickle
import dateutil.relativedelta as dr
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)

def get_standard_and_poors_500_constituents():
    fname = (
        os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + "/sp500_constituents.pkl"
    )
    try:
        # URL request, URL opener, read content.
        req = request.Request(
            "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies"
        )
        opener = request.urlopen(req)
        # Convert bytes to UTF-8.
        content = opener.read().decode()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
        # HTML table we actually need is the first.
        tables = soup.find_all("table")     
        external_class = tables[0].findAll("a", {"class":"external text"})
        c = [ext.string for ext in external_class if not "reports" in ext]

        with open(fname, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(c, f)

    except URLError:
        with open(fname, "rb") as f:
            c = pickle.load(f)
    finally:
        return c


sp500_constituents = get_standard_and_poors_500_constituents()
spdr_etf = "SPY"
sp500_index = "^GSPC"

def main():
    X = get_standard_and_poors_500_constituents()
    print(X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you analyze the behaviour in regard to the two cases? Why are you using ```sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)```? And i would be nervous about your usage of variable c... This might be a local-scope problem (but i'm not sure how try-except-finally is working).

Comment: You correctly suspect that the recursion limit is causing problems. If I remove it, the code runs okay. But why does that matter?

Comment: Honestly: i have no idea. But it's something you should never change without a reason (because it's changing the behaviour of the python-interpreter). There are some recursive-functions which need this, but most of the time, this parameter should be set to some sane value. I hope it is really the solution to your problem, because i'm as puzzled as you are.

Comment: I have often found that when pickling complicated objects a large recursion limit is required. Hence I sometimes set this value when the object to be pickled is simple (in this case just a list).

Comment: Interesting. It's the second time today reading about recursion-limit and pickle. Maybe another pickle-library like dill helps. But thats not my expertise. I sometimes pickle gigabytes of data. Never had problems. But these always were very bare-to-metal objects like sparse-matrices.